# Error "no suitable constructor found for FirebaseListAdapter()" in Android

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebaseui

I have no idea about neither `Firebase` nor `Arduino`....
But I wrote this code, referring to the video of David East.
So I am getting an error, please help me solve it.

The error is:

> Error:(66, 52) error: no suitable constructor found for FirebaseListAdapter()
>   constructor FirebaseListAdapter.FirebaseListAdapter(Activity,Class,int,Firebase) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   constructor FirebaseListAdapter.FirebaseListAdapter(Activity,Class,int,Query) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

This is the code for MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.devashish.sprout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Firebase mRootRef;
ArrayList<String> mMessages= new ArrayList<>();

TextView mTextView;
ListView mListView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();



    mTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewCondition);
    mListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    mRootRef = new Firebase("https://pleaserun.firebaseio.com");
    Firebase messagesRef=mRootRef.child("condition");
    final FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter= new FirebaseListAdapter<String>() {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) {
            TextView textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(s);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    };



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I changed the line you mentioned to this: final FirebaseListAdapter adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(this,String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_‌​1,messagesRef)

It is now giving error: Error:(71, 38) error: variable adapter might not have been initialized

Comment: Please reword your question, it isn't clear what you are trying to do. What line is the error on? Is it this line? `final FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter= new FirebaseListAdapter<String>()`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the constructor arguments that are needed for `FirebaseListAdapter`. Probably something like this in your case:

```
final FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter= new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
  this,         /* the activity */
  String.class, /* the data type that you're reading from Firebase */
  android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, /* the layout for each item */
  messagesRef   /* the Query/Firebase location to read the data from */
) {
  ...
```

Note that this is all reasonably well [documented in the FirebaseUI repo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview), in the associated [FirebaseUI codelab](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/codelabs/chat) or otherwise the error message from Android Studio.

Comment: I changed the line you mentioned to this:
        final FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this,String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,messagesRef)                                                                                                                        It is now giving error: Error:(71, 38) error: variable adapter might not have been initialized

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the firebaseui dependency, use this

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
```

i had the same issue, the error was gone once i changed it. remove your current firebaselistadapter code and re-write it again. Good luck